# Variance of Variance -> Confidence Interval?

Tags: statistics, variance, monte-carlo

let's consider some random variables collected in the vector $X$ following the distribution $f_X(X)$. We want to compute the probability that:

$$
p = \textrm{Pr} [G(X) < 0]
$$

where $G(X)$ is some arbitrary function.
In general, this probability can be computed by pure Monte Carlo simulation. Just draw $N$ samples and count how many lie beyond the failure boundary $G(X) = 0$:

$$
\hat{p} = \frac{N_{G<0}}{N}
$$

The variance of this estimate is given by:
$$
\textrm{Var}[\hat{p}] = \frac{p(1-p)}{N} \approx \frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{N}
$$

In our problem, we substitute the expensive-to-evaluate function $G(X)$ with a surrogate model $\hat{G}(X)$ which means that the number of failure samples $N_{G<0}$ might not be correct, i.e. it has its own variance (which we can compute). Using the [Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method), the variance of the variance of the probability estimate can be computed:

$$
\textrm{Var}[\textrm{Var}[\hat{p}]]
$$

Now the final question:
How can we use this to determine some confidence interval of $\hat{p}$?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Correction: $\mathrm{Var}[\hat p] = p(1-p)/N$, which you can estimate with $\hat p (1 - \hat p) / N$. Also, do you know if your surrogate model is unbiased for $N_{G < 0}$?

Comment: Oh yes you're right. Got it confused with the coefficient of variation. No I don't know if that holds

Comment: Unfortunately, if you can't control the bias in $\hat G$, you can't really give a confidence interval. You could give an interval for the mean under $\hat G$, but there's no guarantee it would describe $G$.

Comment: As a surrogate model for $G$, we are using Kriging to create $\hat{G}$ and Kriging gives both a mean and a variance for the prediction. Doesn't that help with the problem if you know the variance of each prediction?

Comment: The mean and variance given by kriging are the posterior mean and variance; they're Bayesian calculations, not frequentist ones. You can use them to give a Bayesian credible interval, but that's a different thing from a frequentist confidence interval. (On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging), note the bands on the graph are labelled as "credible intervals".)

Comment: So is there any way to use both the error due to the limited number of samples (the variance of the monte carlo predictor) and the error of the Kriging prediction to come up with some metric that gives a sense of the variance of the probability estimate?